# Javascript Tabulator isn't sorting the times in the dates column

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

so the datetime is sorted in my database like so:

```
Wed, 21 Jun 2023 19:03:11 GMT
```

Now I am using tabulator sorting by the date, however, it is ignoring the times and not sorting by the time.

For example:

```
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:26:17 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:30:46 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:33:39 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:33:41 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:36:17 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:36:26 GMT
Thu, 22 Jun 2023 01:06:16 GMT
```

As you can see it's upside down and should be sorting by the time too making the latest date time on top of the table. I have tried adding the sorter to "datetime" but that just broke the sorting completely. I understand it wants some kind of format off me like %x%y%w% etc but I'm not sure what format mine is in terms of that format.

Help is much appreciated.

My code for sorting:

```
initialSort:[
                {column:"date", dir:"asc"},
            ],
            columns:[                 //define the table columns
                //sorter params for datetime column in this format Thu, 22 Jun 2023 00:26:17 GMT
                {title:"Date", field:"date", editor:"output"}, //I have tried sorter:"datetime" but it broke the table as i think it wants additional info like the format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom sorter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/sort#func-custom), but in your case maybe you just want to use `dir: "desc"` instead of `dir: "asc"` ? because the list you showed seems to be sorted.

Here's how you can define and compare using a custom sorter. As you can see, this format is easily parsed to a `Date` object, which makes me think Tabulator should be able to handle it.

```js
var str = "Wed, 21 Jun 2023 19:03:11 GMT";
var date = new Date(str);
console.log(date)

var column = {
  title: "Date",
  field: "date",
  sorter: function sorter(a, b, aRow, bRow, column, dir, sorterParams) {
    var date_a = new Date(a)
    var date_b = new Date(b)
    var diff = date_a.getTime() - date_b.getTime();
    return dir == "asc" ? diff : -diff;
  }
}
```